# How can an object be accessed that inherits from a generic class?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

This cracks my head, I hope somebody will have the wiliness to find a solution.
Right below is a simplified code of the situation. The objective here is, that I wanth a separate, reusable library and to have the option of customizing these classes for each implementation. So i went for inheritance:

```cs
namespace Library {

   //a class that holds stuff together
   public class Core<THandler> where THandler:Handler
   {
      public THandler handler;
      public string text = "Something";
   }

   //class that react for extern events, say a keyboard events
   public class Handler 
   {
      protected object core;
      public Handler(object _core) {
         core = _core;
      }
      protected virtual void OnEvent() {
         //how to access 'core.text' ??
         var a = (Core<Handler>)core; //raises System.InvalidCastException 
                                      // since 'core' actualy contains 
                                      // an instance of MyCore
      }
   }
}
```

```
namespace MyImplementation {
   public class MyCore : Library.Core<MyHandler>
   {
   }

   public class MyHandler : Library.Handler
   {
      protected override void OnEvent() {
         base.OnEvent();
         //and what's the preferable option for accessing 'core' here?
         var a = (MyCore)core; //I use this
      }
   }
}
```

Since Handler.core contains an instance of MyCore, how can one access this object inside Hanlder.OnEventmethod?

Comment: Does Core has to be a generic class? I don't see a lot of benefit. It would be quite straightforward if you could just inject the handler into core via the constructor.

Comment: No, of course, it doesn't have to be generic at any cost. But think of all the explicit casting to access stuff defined in descendand classes.. Though not sure if it is performance issue, surely it would mess up the code a little bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are better off with using interfaces to bind `Core` and `Handler` to each other. You can still keep `Core<T>` generic. Generic type contraints wouldn't allow you to declare circular dependencies, which would otherwise be necessary to make your core work.

Note that the root cause for the problematic cast to be invalid is *not* that `core` instance is `MyCore` from your example, but because `MyCore` inherits from `Core<MyHandler>` and not `Core<Handler>`.

In case, for some reason, you'd insist of keeping the current design, you can make `Handler` generic as well, passing in its ancestor as type parameter, and fixing the cast like this:

```
public class Handler<THandler> where THandler : Handler<THandler>
{
    protected object core;
    public Handler(object _core) {
        core = _core;
    }
    public virtual void OnEvent() {
        // this works
        var a = (Core<THandler>)core;
    }
 }
```

So, to make it a bit more type-safe and avoid casts, the constructor should look like this:

```
    protected Core<THandler> core;
    public Handler(Core<THandler> _core) {
        core = _core;
    }
```

The `MyHandler` declaration would then, quite naturally, look like this:

```
public class MyHandler : Handler<MyHandler>
{
    …
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a try. it sounds exactly like what I wanted!

Answer (score 3):

The best approach here (in my mind, anyway) is to create an interface for the methods and properties that you need to access in `Core`.

For example, something similar to the following:

```
namespace Library {

    public interface ICore {
        string text {get; set;}
    }

   //a class that holds stuff together
    public class Core<THandler> : ICore where THandler : Handler
    {
        public THandler handler;
        private string m_Text = "Something";
        public string text
        {
            get
            {
                return m_Text;
            }
            set
            {
                m_Text = value;
            }
        }
    }

   //class that react for extern events, say a keyboard events
   public class Handler 
   {
      protected ICore core;
      public Handler(object _core) {
         core = (ICore)_core;
      }
      protected virtual void OnEvent() {
          Debug.WriteLine(core.text);
      }
   }
}

namespace MyImplementation {
   public class MyCore : Library.Core<MyHandler>
   {
   }

   public class MyHandler : Library.Handler
   {
      protected override void OnEvent() {
         base.OnEvent();
         //and what's the preferable option for accessing 'core' here?
         var a = (MyCore)core; //I use this
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Good thought, however at the end this breaks the reason why I've gone for generics at all. Within Handler it would work flawlessly, but accessing MyCore within MyHandler it would make me to need to cast core field - since ICore cannot implement My-whatever-stuff

Answer (score 0):

The cast failes because Core is not covariant. Classes in general can not be covariant. Only interfaces and delegates can be covariant.

To reach the expected behaviour you can define the Core class as an interface with a out parameter, like below

```
public interface ICore<out T>where T:Handler
{
    T Handler {get;}
    string Text { get; }
}
```